# VS2013 warning C4172 on return Rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, type-erasure, rvalue

Rvalues are new, so i have some doubts about it...

VS2013 gives

```
warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary
```

for this line

```
return (std::wstring&&)         (*(std::wstring*)v);
```

Is this code (below) unportable and/or have undefined behavior anywhere? If there is - where and why? Am i doing something wrong?
Or this is just a false-positive warning of the VS2013 compiler, and i should just put pragma to ignore it in this paticular case?

temp_value_t is intended to use as a container for a cascade of calls:

[typed value] -> calls virtual_func1(temp_value_t) -> calls virtual_func2(temp_value_t) -> ...  -> calls virtual_funcLAST(temp_value_t)

and funcLAST implementation knows if temp_value_t is really rvalue or lvalue, so funcLAST know which function should be used.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class temp_value_t
    {
    private:
        intptr_t v;
    public:
        temp_value_t(const std::wstring& s)
            {
            v = (intptr_t)&s;
            };

        temp_value_t(std::wstring&& s)
            {
            v = (intptr_t)&s;
            };

        std::wstring&& get_as_temp()
            {
            return (std::wstring&&)         (*(std::wstring*)v);
            };

        const std::wstring& get_as_const()
            {
            return (const std::wstring&)    (*(std::wstring*)v);
            };
    };

void test(temp_value_t v, bool is_param_const)
    {
    std::wstring s;

    if(is_param_const)
        s = v.get_as_const();
    else
        s = v.get_as_temp();

    std::wcout <<  L"Inner = '" << s << L"'\n";
    }; 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    {
    std::wcout <<  L"Test with temp:\n";
    std::wstring s(L"abc");
    test(s, false);
    std::wcout <<  L"Outer = '" << s << L"'\n";
    }

    std::wcout <<  L"\n\n";

    {
    std::wcout <<  L"Test with const:\n";
    std::wstring s(L"abc");
    test(s, true);
    std::wcout <<  L"Outer = '" << s << L"'\n";
    }

    return 0;
    }

/*
VS2013 results:
    Test with temp:
    Inner = 'abc'
    Outer = ''


    Test with const:
    Inner = 'abc'
    Outer = 'abc'

So all works fine... 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store a reference of the given string?

```
class temp_value_t
{
    private:
        const std::wstring & v;
    public:
        temp_value_t(const std::wstring & s)
            : v(s)
        {
        }

        // You can't store reference if you are expecting an rvalue.
        // Because, that rvalue is going to or may expire soon,
        // and when that happens, the stored reference will be invalid.
        //temp_value_t(std::wstring && s)
        //  : v(std::move(s))
        //{
        //}

        // This will already return an rvalue.
        // It is meaningless to cast it to (std::wstring&&).
        std::wstring get_as_temp()
        {
            return v;
        }

        const std::wstring & get_as_const()
        {
            return v;
        }
};
```

If you aim is to store a string object which is passed as an rvalue reference, define a move constructor, and store the rvalue string locally inside the object.

Comment: The const reference will also bind to an rvalue, and be just as dangling.

Comment: @BoPersson The rvalue will vanish when the scoop ends. I meant that.

Comment: hkBattousai, your implementation of get_as_temp calls basic_string(const _Myt& _Right) - you can see it in debug - breakpoint on return and walk into, so this, in fact, returns **a copy** of a string - **which is really bad (long operation), because rvalue is a feature designed specially to avoid this**, and this copy is rvalue. My implementation dont have this additional copy. About reference - reference, pointer or intptr_t is same for this - type erasure anyway (type isn't known inside class), i just used intptr_t to show clearly "type is unknown inside class".

Comment: So "It is meaningless to cast it to (std::wstring&&)" - incorrect, this cast removes additional copy and constructor call.

Comment: " You can't store reference if you are expecting an rvalue." - this class (temp_value_t) itself isn't stored, it is only used as a parameter for functions. This rvalue reference cant expire while in call, when the call returns - temp_value_t is destructed prior to rvalue.